# core 2.0 and office interop - where is the microsoft.office.core package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, office-interop, asp.net-core-2.0

In a standard .NET app, 
I can add the COM objects for Office Core, Word, Excel, and Powerpoint.  Everything works fine.

The Office core assembly is needed for some commands (for example, powerpoint uses Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse/True commands for some actions, and word uses AutomationSecurity via Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.

The problem is when I am building an asp net core app.  Nuget has the packages for Excel, Word, and Powerpoint,  which will work properly if I don't reference any Office.Core items, but anytime I reference one I get this error:

`The type 'MsoTriState' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.`

I've tried manually adding the MSO.DLL to the project, but still get the same error.

I've also tried adding all the COM objects instead of the nuget packages, but I get an error like this on object creation:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

How do I add the Microsoft.Office.Core package to my asp net core 2.0 application?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866895/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-office-interop-word-version-12-0-0-0

Comment: It is not, I have also tried copying the references to the project directory.  My issue is getting Microsoft.Office.Core to play nicely with asp net core.

Comment: Another question might be what the heck is Office interop doing in an ASP.NET application....

Comment: Mathieu - What? You can't see that someone would want to generate a pre-filled outlook email for an office setting where they don't have access to the SMTP server information?  Or that they might want to build an excel report directly from code in an office setting?  Not everyone uses WebApps for playtime on the internet.

Comment: @TimJones Neither of these tasks should involve starting up an actual instance of Outlook or Excel on the server. Doing so is known to cause problems and is [explicitly unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28649911/11683).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative (until someone is able to provide a real answer), I have been playing with the NetOffice nuget packages instead, as they provide the core package that seems to be missing from the official Microsoft Office nuget packages.